# Is it okay to use page template as contact page?

Tags: page-template, seo

I am converting my html website into wordpress. Is it okay to use page template as contact page?
For example you have contact-us.html

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- contact page content code goes here -->
</body>
</html>`

then you just change the header and footer into

`<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- contact page content code goes here -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Is it seo friendly?

Comment: I guess the literal answer is "yes" however I don't see why you'd actively work around WordPress...

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can use page template for your contact page.
2. Page templates have nothing to do with SEO. The contents inside the page template do.